# MVC 4 - LogOff controller action giving 404 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-404

I'm just wrapping up a college project, I'm not sure if I've been staring at my computer for too long and am missing something obvious, but when I try to log a user out, I'm getting a 404 not found for the URL /Account/LogOff.

I have a navbar that shows Log in/Log out depending on whether a user is, logged in, or, logged out:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav pull-right">
        <li class="dropdown" id="dropdown-login-div">
            @if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign In <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account")
            }
            <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-login">
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Account/_LoginPartial.cshtml", new ViewDataDictionary<LetLord.Models.LoginModel>())
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In my Account controller the default LogOff action that comes with the Internet template:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    WebSecurity.Logout();

    return View("Index");
}
```

Could someone tell me why this happening - before I throw my laptop against the wall. Cheers.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You use a link (`<a/>` tag) to log off which results in **HTTP GET** request when user clicks on it, but your action is constrained to serve **POST** request only (because it is decorated with `[HttpPost]` attribute).

You either need to put your link into a form and generate POST request, or remove `[HttpPost]` and `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` (credits to GalacticCowboy) from your action.

Comment: This is correct - and my recommendation would be to remove the HttpPost rather than creating a form to logout.  Since you're not submitting any data to the server, a GET is most appropriate for a logout action.

Comment: `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` will fail since it's not a form post, also.

Comment: Completely went over my head. Thanks.

Comment: Dont use Get for logout ( logout it modifies sever state

Comment: @JeanJimenez There is no correct solution. A solution can only be correct if the other options are not correct.

Comment: @CasBloem: `x * x = 4 => x = 2, x = -2` QED

Comment: This is not a solution. It is work around. Without `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` anyone can hit that get request.

Answer (score 34):

Since logout modifies server state, I wouldnt remove [HttpPost] and [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
Instead I will replace the link (anchor tag) with the following

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Log Out", "Account", FormMethod.Post,
 new { id = "logoutForm" }))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log Out</a>

}
```

Comment: very good solution dude, easy to implement and explains the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue on a legacy app. The way that I fixed it was to detect when the supplied return Url was '/Account/LogOff' and act accordingly.
From the 'AccountController.cs' file, 'Login' method:

```
if (returnUrl == "/Account/LogOff")
    {
        return this.RedirectToLocal(null);
    }
    else
    {
        return this.RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);  
    }
```